# Search for a specific string in a page resource from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and would like to read one of the page resources from where the extension is invoked. The main page contains many  resources and I would like read a particular resource (an ASP file) and search that ASP file for a specific string to be populated in my extension.

The page structure (simplified) is as below:

```
A.asp
  |-- xxx
  |-- yyy
B.asp
  |--- some file
  |--- some file
C.asp
```

The string I am interested is in C.asp and is defined as two variables.

```
var mySummary = "Summary Text";
var titleUnescape = document.createElement("DIV");
titleUnescape.innerHTML = mySummary;
mySummarySummary = titleUnescape.textContent||titleUnescape.innerText||"";

var mySummaryPrefix = "Information I want ";
titleUnescape.innerHTML = mySummaryPrefix;
mySummaryPrefix = titleUnescape.textContent||titleUnescape.innerText||"";
```

How can I extract **Summary Text & Information I want** from the ASP file?

Comment: The final code of the main page is the one that I posted which contains a bunch of ASP files. I want to extract the values assigned to mySummary and mySummaryPrefix from chrome extension from one of the page resources (ASP file).

Comment: All the comments from Raul seem to be lost. @RaúlMartin Please can you post your suggestions again